# Converting XML into FHIR Resource XML format

Tags: xml, xslt, wso2, hl7-fhir, wso2-esb

I am currently trying to convert data from standard XML format to a format matching FHIR Resource XML.

I am trying to research multiple avenues. Currently, I am fixated on using WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus to see whether it has the required functionality. 
However, I suspect using an XSLT script may be useful for my purposes. I was just hoping for a discussion on possible methods that they may know of for this conversion process.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT is certainly one option and it looks like using WSO2 would do it.  Depending on your architecture, WSO2 might be heavier than you need.  If you're just looking at converting instances, a simple XSLT engine would do.  You could also do the work in code (Java, C#, whatever).

One benefit of doing it in code is that if you convert from a DOM representation of your source XML to the FHIR reference implementation data model is that you'd be able to produce both XML and JSON (and eventually RDF).  You could do that using XSLT as well, but would then need a two-stage process which would be slower.

Another consideration is what will be easiest to maintain.  I love XSLT, but it takes a certain mindset to write and maintain it, so make sure you've got a few people on staff who are comfortable with it if you want to go that route.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I appreciate it. I have just learned that the incoming data could be in XML or JSON, so XSLT may not be the best option any more.

Comment: There are mapping tools out there like MapForce that support converting between a variety of syntaxes, including JSON, so that might be useful.  Or you can just write code :>